# get all relational tables data using xmlelement in pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, xmlelement

I need to get all the connected tables data while getting values as xml

Till now I can produce specific table results as below,

**Table1**

```
id  name    rollNo
1   aaa     10
2   bbb     15
```

**Table2**

```
id  rollNo  div
1   10       a
2   15       b
```

**Query**

```
SELECT XMLElement("table1", 
XMLAttributes(t.id, t.name, t.rollno))
AS "RESULT"
FROM table1 t where t.rollno=15
```

**Result**

```
<table1 id="2" name="bbb" rollno="15"></table1>
```

But this way, I am able to get data for specific table only.
I want to get the xml data for all the tables related with parent table by foreign key.

Suppose, here table3 is related with table1 or table 4 is related with table 3, That should also come in generated xml. Basically I am looking for full tree.

**Expected result:**

```
<table1 id="2" name="bbb" rollno="15"></table1>
<table2 id="2" rollno="15" div="b"></table2>
<table3.. and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that combines data dictionary queries to find parent-child relationships and `DBMS_XMLGEN.GETXML` to generate and combine XML.

The below function takes a `ROWID`, finds the parent and child table, and generates XML for the relevant rows.  There are many assumptions here, and this may take a huge amount of work to get working with real data.

```
create or replace function get_related_xml(p_rowid rowid) return xmltype is
    v_child_table_owner varchar2(128);
    v_child_table_name varchar2(128);

    v_parent_table_owner varchar2(128);
    v_parent_table_name varchar2(128);
    v_column varchar2(128);

    v_child_xml xmltype;
    v_parent_xml xmltype;
    v_combined_xml xmltype;
begin
    --Get child table directly referenced by ROWID.
    select owner, object_name
    into v_child_table_owner, v_child_table_name
    from all_objects
    where object_type = 'TABLE'
        and object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(p_rowid);

    --Get parent table based on child table ROWID, and join columns.
    --(ASSUMPTION: Tables only have one column, with the same name, that joins the tables.)
    select owner, table_name, column_name
    into v_parent_table_owner, v_parent_table_name, v_column
    from all_cons_columns
        where (owner, constraint_name) in
        (
            --Foreign key constraints based on the relevant table.
            select r_owner, r_constraint_name
            from all_constraints
            where constraint_type = 'R'
                and (owner, table_name) in
                (
                    --Table referenced by ROWID.
                    select owner, object_name
                    from all_objects
                    where object_type = 'TABLE'
                        and object_id = dbms_rowid.rowid_object(p_rowid)
                )
        );

    --Generate child XML.
    v_child_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType
        (
            'select c.*
            from '||v_child_table_owner||'.'||v_child_table_name||' c
            join '||v_parent_table_owner||'.'||v_parent_table_name||' p
                on c.'||v_column||' = p.'||v_column||'
            where c.rowid = '''||p_rowid||''''
        );

    --Generate parent XML.
    v_parent_xml := dbms_xmlgen.getXMLType
        (
            'select p.*
            from '||v_child_table_owner||'.'||v_child_table_name||' c
            join '||v_parent_table_owner||'.'||v_parent_table_name||' p
                on c.'||v_column||' = p.'||v_column||'
            where c.rowid = '''||p_rowid||''''
        );

    --Combine the XML and return them.
    select xmlconcat(v_child_xml, v_parent_xml)
    into v_combined_xml
    from dual;

    return v_combined_xml;
end get_related_xml;
/
```

Calling the function is easy.  The current version doesn't return data in exactly the format you want, you may need to transform the XML.

```
select get_related_xml(rowid)
from table1
where rollno=15;

<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <NAME>bbb</NAME>
  <ROLLNO>15</ROLLNO>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
<ROWSET>
 <ROW>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <ROLLNO>15</ROLLNO>
  <DIV>b</DIV>
 </ROW>
</ROWSET>
```

Here's the sample schema I used to generate the above results.  This is a simple schema, with only one parent-child relationship, based on a single column that has the same name in both tables.

```
create table table2(id number primary key, rollNo number unique, div varchar2(100));
insert into table2
select 1, 10, 'a' from dual union all
select 2, 15, 'b' from dual;

create table table1(id number primary key, name varchar2(100), rollNo number,
    constraint table1_fk foreign key (rollNo) references table2(rollNo));
insert into table1
select 1, 'aaa', 10 from dual union all
select 2, 'bbb', 15 from dual;
```

Comment: Thanks will try it out and let you know